# CALayer setContents is not working on 10.5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, calayer, nswindow

I have following code

```
[[mWindow contentView] setWantsLayer:YES]; //mWindow is NSWindow object
[[mWindow contentView] layer].contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
```

This code is working fine on 10.6 but on 10.5 `mWindow` is showing nothing. Why?

```
NSlog(@"%@",[[mWindow contentView] layer].contents)  //10.5
NSImage 0x15d030 Size={565, 305} Reps=(
    NSBitmapImageRep 0x166400 Size={565, 305} ColorSpace=NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace BPS=8 BPP=24 Pixels=565x305 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=0
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you cannot pass an `NSImage` to `setContents:` in 10.5. See the docs for [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

> contents An object that provides the contents of the layer.
>   Animatable.
>
> @property(retain) id contents Discussion The default value of this
>   property is nil. When this property is nil, the layer contents are
>   rendered to a layer-managed backing store.
>
> You can set this property to a CGImageRef to present the contents of
>   the image in place of the layer’s contents. **(In OS X 10.6 and later,
>   you can also set it to an NSImage object.)** Assigning an image to this
>   property replaces the layer’s own backing store with the image’s
>   content.
>
> Availability Available in OS X v10.5 and later. See Also   @property
>   contentsRect Related Sample Code LightTable Declared In CALayer.h